# What program can I use to benchmark network traffic?

Tags: linux, networking, performance-tuning, benchmark

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to test real network throughput between two points?](https://serverfault.com/questions/5111/how-to-test-real-network-throughput-between-two-points)

Given two computers connected by some network interface, is there a standard tool used by  an academics publishing in peer-reviewed journals to benchmark performance across that interface?

Comment: Dup/Related http://serverfault.com/questions/5111/how-to-test-real-network-throughput-between-two-points

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test run netperf, Nettest or TTCP. not sure of the industry standard status thou.

Offtopic: new users aren't allowed to add hyperlinks?

Comment: I'm not sure, but it may be the case that you need to use markdown syntax.

Answer (score 1):

To use [iperf](https://iperf.fr/) first start it in server mode at one end:

```
iperf -s
```

Next, run it in client mode at the other end, specifying the IP address of the server node:

```
iperf -c xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -d
```

Answer (score 0):

I like **bwm-ng**.